# What is meant by 'JavaScript Namespacing'?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Namespacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684452/javascript-namespacing)

Im pretty new to JavaScript and was wondering if anyone could give me a good description of what is meant by JavaScript Namespacing?

Also any resources e.g. articles etc, are much appreciated on the subject.

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684452/javascript-namespacing OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712231/javascript-and-namespacing

Comment: Take a look at this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231088/javascript-namespace-is-this-a-good-pattern

Answer (score 40):

JavaScript is designed in such a way that it is very easy to create global variables that have the potential to interact in negative ways.  The practice of namespacing is usually to create an object literal encapsulating your own functions and variables, so as not to collide with those created by other libraries:

```
var MyApplication = {
  var1: someval,
  var2: someval,
  myFunc: function() {
    // do stuff
  }
};
```

Then instead of calling `myFunc()` globally, it would always be called as:

```
MyApplication.myFunc();
```

Likewise, `var1` always accessed as:

```
console.log(MyApplication.var1);
```

In this example, all of our application's code has been namespaced inside `MyApplication`. It is therefore far less likely that our variables will collide with those created by other libraries or created by the DOM.

Answer (score 6):

I use this namespacing technique, along with "use strict" outlined by [Crockford](https://azuredays.com/2014/04/04/object-javascript-scope-namespaces-use-strict/)

```
var MyNamespace = (function () {
    "use strict"; 

    function SomeOtherFunction() {

    }

    function Page_Load() {

    }

    return { //Expose 
        Page_Load: Page_Load,
        SomeOtherFunction: SomeOtherFunction
    };
} ());

MyNamespace.Page_Load();
```

Answer (score 3):

Read up on a simple tutorial [Here](http://blog.stannard.net.au/2011/01/14/creating-namespaces-in-javascript/)

Namespacing is used to avoid polluting the global namespace (no window. variables). In truth, each namespace is just a big variable, that has many properties and methods.

This happens, because in javascript you can have whole functions (methods) as variables

Comment: Link is dead. Maybe use [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20141209002145/http://blog.stannard.net.au/2011/01/14/creating-namespaces-in-javascript/) from archive.org?